# number of sheets of covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are integers with $ad-bc\ne 0$ and write the torus $T$ as $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb C^2: 1=|x|=|y|\}.$ Consider the map $p: T\to T$ defined by $(x,y)\to (x^ay^b,x^cy^d)$.

I am able to prove that $p$ is a covering space.

> I want to now find the cardinality $|p^{-1}(x_0)|$ for each $x_0\in
> T$.

Could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: A little advance : we can look at $p^{-1}(1,1)$. The system is then $x^ay^b = 1, x^cy^d = 1$. Playing a bit with it, it is the same, assuming that $a \neq c$ as the system $y^{b \frac{b-d}{a-c}} = 1, x = y^{\frac{b-d}{a-c}}.$

Comment: @N.H. I don't quite follow. Does that follow the strategy I outlined?

Comment: it does not and I don't think it works in fact. I'll write something if this method works, sorry.

Comment: @N.H. Do you see how I can use the linear map $(ax+by, cx+dy)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use $(u, v)$ for the complex coordinates, so that we can write
$$
u = e^{ix},\quad
v = e^{iy}.
$$
Since $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers, the map $p$ sends $(u, v) = (e^{ix}, e^{iy})$ to
$$
(u^{a} v^{b}, u^{c} v^{d}) = (e^{(ax + by)i}, e^{(cx + dy)i}).
$$
It should be apparent that the lift $\hat{f}$ of $p$ is as in the hint.

To count the number of sheets in the covering $p$, consider the image of some fundamental domain, such as the unit square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ under $\hat{f}$, and ask "how many unit squares" the image covers (i.e., *what is its area*?).

The number of sheets is:

> $|\det \hat{f}| = |ad - bc|$.

Comment: Sorry if I require more explication, (and thank you), but I don't see how to get the number of sheets by using the determinant of the linear map. Maybe I don't know much about the determinant, but how do you get from considering the image of the unit square to computing the determinant?

Comment: To be more specific, why does determining the area lead us to $|p^{-1}(x_0)|$?

Comment: It may help to look at simple cases: Think of a sheet of graph paper, with each square being a fundamental domain for the torus. If you stretch by a factor $a$ in one direction, a unit square maps to an $a \times 1$ rectangle, which wraps $|a|$ times around the torus. Generally, the area of the image of the unit square counts "how many times" the unit square covers the unit square under $p$. (The absolute value of the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is well-known to be the area of the image of the unit square under the associated linear operator.)